# Issues with a random number generator upon pushing a button and telling if number is even or odd

Tags: c, if-statement, random, while-loop

The issue is that I push the button, the console gives me a number. I push the button again, and THEN it tells me if its even or odd, and immediately spits out yet another random number. I want the random number and even/odd to happen within the same time of pressing the button.

```
if(value==0){   //If button is pushed
  int v1;
  v1 = (rand()%15);
  printf ("Random number: %d\n", v1);    //print random number
  if(v1 % 2 == 0){   //if number is perfectly divided by 2
    printf("%d is even.",v1);      // print the number is even
  }
  else{
    printf("%d is odd.",v1);       //print the number is odd
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a newline at the end of the `printf()` format strings.  Or, at a pinch, use `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: printf doesn't print as soon as its called, it waits for a good moment to print  so fflush can make sure it prints when you want it to

Comment: @TheoWalton while there is a seed of truth in what you are saying, your statement is misleading at best. First of all `printf` is not an async call. Second, `printf` will not "wait". i.e. it is not blocking. It will return as soon as it is called. It is true that under some conditions the message will not be outputed to console during the call to `printf`, but rather cached in a buffer. Even when that happens `printf` - as I've said - will not "wait", it will return immediately.  [cont]

Comment: [cont] Then the actual outputting to console - i.e. flushing - will not happen after "a good moment". It will happen during another call to `printf` where conditions are met for flushing, or on an explicit call to `fflush`. Maybe that is what you meant, but your comment doesn't reflect that.

Comment: Or put in a more concise manner "*The stream `stdout` is line-buffered when it points to a terminal. Partial lines will not appear until `fflush` or `exit` is called, or a newline is printed.*" (`man 3 stdout`)